# Timer and TimerTask in java

Tags: java

I would like to use Java Timer and TimerTask to do a Job everyday evening at 5 O' clock.
Please help me to solve this problem.

Problem with below methods as I think...

```
schedule(TimerTask task, Date time)
```

----Date can be specified for first day only not for forthcomingdays available.

```
schedule(TimerTask task, Date firstTime, long period)
```

----initial starting time and after how long it is to be executed can be given,
here if I start initlally my scheduler at 4 O' Clock evening then how to mention the next execution time. If I set 1 hour delay it will call after every one hour.

```
schedule(TimerTask task, long delay)
```

--This is not applicable which will do things based on start times.

```
schedule(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)
```

--This is not applicable which will do things based on start times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well the more appropriate answer is the one by Grooveek 
but as an alternative

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
public class demo 
{
  Toolkit toolkit;
  Timer timer;
  public demo()
  {
    toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new scheduleDailyTask(), 0, //initial delay
        1 * 1000); //subsequent rate
  }
  class scheduleDailyTask extends TimerTask 
  {
    public void run() 
    {
      Date date = new Date();
      if(date.getHours()==5 && date.getMinutes()==0 && date.getSeconds()==0)
      {
          System.out.println("its 5 O clock");
          System.out.println("run the daily schedule method now");
      }
    }
  }
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    new demo();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you to switch to [Quartz Cron Trigger](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/examples/Example3) which is very light and easy to use

```
SchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
Scheduler sched = sf.getScheduler();
//Job1 is scheduled to run everyday evening at 5 O' clock

JobDetail job = newJob(SimpleJob.class)
    .withIdentity("job1", "group1")
    .build();

CronTrigger trigger = newTrigger()
    .withIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
    .withSchedule(cronSchedule("0 0 17 * * ?"))
    .build();

sched.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

Comment: how to deal the same situation with TimerTask if I don't want Quartz Cron????? Please make me to understand.

Comment: And its free for Industry or what ? because money is important when it goes to corporate.

Comment: Quartz Scheduler is licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0. This license allows you to use it in a commercial product without modification for free

Comment: according to you its free but in their website why and what they say like this.                        Sign Up for a Free 30-Day TrialX uartz Scheduler, including Quartz Where and Quartz Manager, are commercial products based on the open source Quartz project, the de facto job scheduler for Java used in hundreds of thousands of enterprise applications. Fill out the form below to download Quartz Scheduler, Quartz Where and Quartz Manager and receive a 30-day trial license.

Comment: [Download Page](http://quartz-scheduler.org/downloads/catalog). The sentence "Quartz Scheduler is licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0." was directly copy-pasted from [this page](http://quartz-scheduler.org/overview/license-and-copyright). It IS free. Terracotta monetizes enteprise products built upon Quartz (Quartz Enterprise with distributed capabilities is not free for example), but the Quartz library is free to use

Comment: but they didn't mention anything as free. you mentioned like this in your first comments.

Comment: From the [Apache License website](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0) `2. Grant of Copyright License. Subject to the terms and conditions of this License, each Contributor hereby grants to You a perpetual, worldwide, non-exclusive, no-charge, royalty-free, irrevocable copyright license to reproduce, prepare Derivative Works of, publicly display, publicly perform, sublicense, and distribute the Work and such Derivative Works in Source or Object form.` We use it in several of our deployments

Answer (score 1):

try

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.clear(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
    c.clear(Calendar.MINUTE);
    c.clear(Calendar.SECOND);
    if (c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) > 17) {
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 17);
    Date firstTime = c.getTime();
    new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(task, firstTime, 24 * 3600 * 1000);
```

Comment: according to you I will run the Timer for a very short period which will check the time and if it matches then it will do the task.

Comment: fixed my example to be more understandable. if you print firstTime you will see Tue Jan 22 17:00:00 EET 2013.